# Update ListView item's drawable state when child clicked

Tags: android, listview, linkify

The problem:

I have a `ListView` item with a relatively complex layout. One of the children in the list item view is a `TextView` with links. The `TextView` can handle the clicks on links found in it(by using `Linkify`), and has a `OnClickListener` that handles click on parts of the text that are not links. The listener will just get the position of the view in the `ListView` and perform a click:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int position = mListView.getPositionForView(v);
    mListView.performItemClick(v, position, mAdapter.getItemId(position));
}
```

Everything works fine, except the click doesn't trigger the `ListView` to update the list item's drawable state. It does trigger that when you click on other `TextView`s in the item that are not clickable.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to do mListView.invalidateViews()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working.

Set the list item view `clickable` and set its background as a `state-list` drawable, also set `addStatesFromChildren` to `true`. This will make sure the state of the list view item is changed when any of its children is clicked(assume the child is clickable).

However, this will cause the `ListView` itself not receiving focus, so you need to handle the click by adding `View.OnClickListener` to the list item itself instead of adding a `OnItemClickedListener` to the `ListView`.